# Julia redefining indices when accessing an array

Tags: indexing, julia

I have a structure implementing the Array interface. I want to redefine the indices when accessing it. So far, I did it in the `Base.getindex` function for my type, but I have seen the `Base.to_indices` function in the doc and do not know how they work together.

It is possible to access array elements using `:` (`Colon`), `UnitRange`, `StepRange`, `OneTo`, `Int` or `Int arrays`, so where should I redefine the indices without having to manage all these cases?

Comment: What do you mean by "redefine"?  Could you give an example of what you want to happen?

Comment: e.g, permute the indices and apply a transformation to them (`i = f(i)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to talk about this in the abstract.  Here's a concrete example:

```
struct ReversedRowMajor{T,A} <: AbstractMatrix{T}
    data::A
end
ReversedRowMajor(data::AbstractMatrix{T}) where {T} = ReversedRowMajor{T, typeof(data)}(data)
Base.size(R::ReversedRowMajor) = reverse(size(R.data))
Base.getindex(R::ReversedRowMajor, i::Int, j::Int) = R.data[end-j+1, end-i+1]
```

This simple array accesses the parent array with its indices permuted (to be row major) and transformed (to be reversed).  Note that this array automatically supports all the expected forms of indexing:

```
julia> R = ReversedRowMajor([1 2; 3 4; 5 6])
2×3 ReversedRowMajor{Int64,Array{Int64,2}}:
 6  4  2
 5  3  1

julia> R[:, isodd.(R[1,:].÷2)]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 6  2
 5  1

julia> @view R[[1,4,5]]
3-element view(reshape(::ReversedRowMajor{Int64,Array{Int64,2}}, 6), [1, 4, 5]) with eltype Int64:
 6
 3
 2
```

Note that we're not re-indexing into `R` with the permuted and computed indices — the new indices are given directly to the parent array `R.data`.

Now, `to_indices`, on the other hand, does simple transformations of previously unsupported index *types* to either `Int` or arrays of `Int` and then re-indexes into `R` itself with those transformed indices.  Note what happens when you call `R[Int8(1),Int8(1)]`:

```
julia> @which R[Int8(1),Int8(1)]
getindex(A::AbstractArray, I...) in Base at abstractarray.jl:925
```

This isn't calling any method you defined — not yet.  You didn't define how to `getindex(::ReversedRowMajor, ::Int8, ::Int8)`. So Julia is handling that case for you.  It uses `to_indices` to convert the `Int8` to an `Int` and then calls `R[1,1]` *again*.  Now it hits the method you defined.

**In short:** This array has a simple `getindex` method with `Int` indices that recomputes accesses into a *parent array*. `to_indices`, on the other hand, transforms all the other types of indices to supported indices *into the same array* in cases where you've not defined a matching method.  You're simply not able to do the sort of transformation you want with `to_indices` because it's not clear if `R[1, 2]` is using the pre-transformed indices or the post-transformed indices.

Comment: You're right, talking about it on this example is easier. In this example (which is not far from what I want to do), there is a performance issue if you call R[:,:] since eachindex will iterate in a non-optimal order for cartesian indices. Is there a way to tell Julia what is the optimal iteration order for this array ?

Comment: question opened: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55415780/how-do-i-tell-julia-in-wich-order-iterate-in-an-array