# How do I tell Julia in which order to iterate in an Array?

Tags: performance, indexing, iteration, julia

[This answser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55382332/6314254) led me to an other question:

When defining a new structure like this one:

```
struct ReversedRowMajor{T,A} <: AbstractMatrix{T}
    data::A
end
ReversedRowMajor(data::AbstractMatrix{T}) where {T} = ReversedRowMajor{T, typeof(data)}(data)
Base.size(R::ReversedRowMajor) = reverse(size(R.data))
Base.getindex(R::ReversedRowMajor, i::Int, j::Int) = R.data[end-j+1, end-i+1]
```

If `R` is a `ReversedRowMajor` array, when accessing `R[:,:]` Julia will iterate through the `CartesianIndices` in the order which should be the fastest for the array i.e. the memory order (see [array performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Access-arrays-in-memory-order,-along-columns-1)) but in this case it's not the expected one, since we are permutating the indices: (i,j) → (end-j+1, end-i+1).

So the question is: given an array, is there a way to tell Julia which axis is the fastest one?

(see also [Multidimensional algorithms and iteration](https://julialang.org/blog/2016/02/iteration))

Comment: Not yet. This is still an open question.  https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15648

Comment: I could accept your comment as an answer, thank you!